# JS compiler to write frontend and backend code simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-construction, google-closure

I would like to write projects with high level of interaction between frontend and backend. Currently I'm using Node.js for backend, Google Closure for frontend and own Swagger-like library to publish and use JSON services based on a schema. I don't like this approach, because changes to such projects are non-local, and need a lot of testing.

Is there a variant of JS (or, possibly, some language translating to JS) translating one source (possibly with some `@server/@client` annotations) both to frontend and backend code?

Answer (score 2):

There are two options which comes into my mind:

- Have a look at the [meteor-Framework](https://www.meteor.com/). They have a way to publish functions to both the client and the server, so you can use one API everywhere.
- If you want to write an application, you can use [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit). There you have got all functionality of an webkit browser plus node functinality all at the global namespace.

Comment: I found meteor the right tool for this job. Though I wish we could use the core as a module in node rather the whole coming as a framework.

Comment: Meteor looks awesome for this task, but it doesn't allow to write back-/frontend source code in one file.